# Logitech K750 stops working after booting

Tags: 12.04, logitech

My `Logitech K750` can work while configuring the bios during boot but once I boot into `Ubuntu 12.04` I get no response. Running `lsusb` on a second keyboard shows both my Logitech keyboard and mouse are connected but they won't respond.

Any ideas? I searched and didn't find anything like this.

Update: I found some cases where the `Logitech Unifying Receiver` fails to respond and is fixed by running the following command: `modprobe -r hid_logitech_dj && modprobe hid_logitech_dj`. I attempted this but the problems persists.

Answer (score 1):

OP posted:

> It seems the solution is a mix of two things, one is the adapter has to be taken out and put back in and the above `modprobe` command must be run.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue 6 years later, only I do not need to run that modprobe command.